# What is the difference between JSFORCE and SFORCE?

Tags: apex, javascript, soap-api, jsforce, sforce

What is the difference between JSFORCE and SFORCE?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here they are:

1. [JSforce](https://jsforce.github.io/):

   - This is a open source plugin to allow developers to connect to Salesforce from JavaScript. Here is **[the list of supported methods](https://jsforce.github.io/document/)**.
   - From documentation:

     > JSforce (f.k.a. Node-Salesforce) is a isomorphic JavaScript library utilizing Salesforce's API: It works both in the browser and with Node.js.
     >
     > It encapsulates the access to various APIs provided by Salesforce in
     >   asynchronous JavaScript function calls.
     >
     > Unlike other Salesforce API libraries, it is intended to give
     >   an integrated interface to both server-side and client-side apps, so you
     >   don't have to rewrite similar logics with different libraries only for
     >   running in a different environment.
     >
     > Additionally, it has a useful command line interface (CLI) which gives
     >   an interactive console (REPL), so you can learn the usage without hassle.
2. [`sforce`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm):

   - Salesforce developed the `sforce` library to support:

     - [`Ajax Toolkit`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm)
     - [`Service Console Integration Toolkit`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm)
     - [Salesforce1 navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)
     - etc.